# Codeigniter + Zend barcode error at Zend/Barcode/Barcode.php

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter, zend-framework2

I always have this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/user/public_html/nameofsite/application/libraries/Zend/Barcode/Barcode.php on line 10

Here is my controller code for generating barcode:

```
public function testbarcode()
{
    require_once('./application/libraries/Zend/Barcode/Barcode.php');
    //adjust the above path to the correct location
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array();
    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
}
```

Barcode.php code:

namespace Zend\Barcode; //this is line 10

use Traversable;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

/**
 * Class for generate Barcode
 */
abstract class Barcode
{
 . . . more code
}

What could be the solution here? I tried a lot of search with this but no luck at all I'm using codeigniter 2.1.3 and zend 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
use namespace Zend\Barcode; //this is line 10
```

**`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`**
says it found a string, although this string was not expected. It could be expecting a colon, i.e.

Anyway, the require that uses Zend\Barcode should be BEFORE the use.
And by what I know, you should require the autoloader for BarCode, not the class directly.

Comment: I tried this one dude, same error

public function testbarcode()
 {
   $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode/Barcode');  
  
  //require_once('./application/libraries/Zend/Barcode/Barcode.php');
  //adjust the above path to the correct location
  $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
  $rendererOptions = array();
  Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
 }

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Zend folder to codeigniter's system/libraries/ and load lib as following

```
public function testbarcode()
{
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');

    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');
    $rendererOptions = array('imageType'=>'png', 'horizontalPosition' => 'center', 'verticalPosition' => 'middle');
    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->render();
    return $imageResource;
}
```

I Hope, Its helpful